# Knowing when AVPlayer object is ready to play

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, audio-streaming, avplayer

I'm trying to play an `MP3` file that is passed to an `UIView` from a previous `UIView` (stored in a `NSURL *fileURL` variable).

I'm initializing an `AVPlayer` with:

```
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

NSLog(@"Player created:%d",player.status);
```

The `NSLog` prints `Player created:0,` which i figured means it is not ready to play yet.

When i click the play `UIButton`, the code i run is:

```
-(IBAction)playButtonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked Play. MP3:%@",[fileURL absoluteString]);

    if(([player status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) && !isPlaying)
//  if(!isPlaying)
    {
        [player play];
        NSLog(@"Playing:%@ with %d",[fileURL absoluteString], player.status);
        isPlaying = YES;
    }
    else if(isPlaying)
    {

        [player pause];
        NSLog(@"Pausing:%@",[fileURL absoluteString]);
        isPlaying = NO;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error in player??");
    }

}
```

When i run this, I always get `Error in player??` in the console.
If i however replace the `if` condition that checks if `AVPlayer` is ready to play, with a simple `if(!isPlaying)`..., then the music plays the SECOND TIME I click on the play `UIButton`.

The console log is:

```
Clicked Play. MP3:http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3
Playing:http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3 **with 0**

Clicked Play. MP3:http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3
Pausing:http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3

Clicked Play. MP3:http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3
2011-03-23 11:06:43.674 Podcasts[2050:207] Playing:http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3 **with 1**
```

I see that the SECOND TIME, the `player.status` seems to hold 1, which I'm guessing is `AVPlayerReadyToPlay`.

What can I do to have the playing to work properly the first time i click the play `UIButton`?
(ie, how can i make sure the `AVPlayer` is not just created, but also ready to play?)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You are playing a remote file. It may take some time for the `AVPlayer` to buffer enough data and be ready to play the file (see [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html))

But you don't seem to wait for the player to be ready before tapping the play button. What I would to is disable this button and enable it only when the player is ready.

Using KVO, it's possible to be notified for changes of the player status:

```
playButton.enabled = NO;
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

This method will be called when the status changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            playButton.enabled = YES;
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            // something went wrong. player.error should contain some information
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked like a charm.
(should have guessed though when i saw it was playing offline files without a problem)

Comment: There are some URL that just don't play, they exists but they don't work (as example iTunes will not play them too). How do you manage that behavior? There's no timeout in AVPlayer.

Comment: @Fabrizio `player.status` should change to `AVPlayerStatusFailed` then (see the edited answer).

Comment: AVPlayerStatusFailed or AVPlayerStatusUnknown is never called. Just to be clear the URL I try to play is: http://audioplayer.wunderground.com:80/RHBrant/Cheyenne.mp3.m3u. I've added an observer to my appDelegate.player but the status is always Ready To Play.

Comment: In my experience `player.currentItem.status` is accurate when `player.status` is not. Not sure what the differences is.

Comment: I am doing the same thing and it is working fine on IOS6 but on IOS7 the observeValueForKeyPath is not getting called ... any idea ?

Comment: @Sosily Did you get solution. I am facing the same problem. in iOS 6 it works perfectly but in iOS 7 observeValueForKeyPath not getting called.

Comment: @iOSAppDev On IOS7 use AVPlayerItem addObserver

Comment: wow, this AVPlayer is so poorly designed that makes me cry. Why not adding a onLoad handler block? Come on Apple, simplify your stuff!

Answer (score 49):

## Swift Solution

```
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

func prepareToPlay() {
    let url = <#Asset URL#>
    // Create asset to be played.
    let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
    
    // Create a new AVPlayerItem with the asset.
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    
    // Register as an observer of the player item's status property.
    self.observer = playerItem.observe(\.status, options:  [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (playerItem, change) in
        if playerItem.status == .readyToPlay {
            // Do your work here.
        }
    })

    // Associate the player item with the player.
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
```

Also you can invalidate the observer this way

```
self.observer.invalidate()
```

**Important:** You must keep the observer variable retained otherwise it will deallocate and the changeHandler will no longer get called. So don't define the observer as a function variable but define it as a instance variable like the given example.

This key value observer syntax is new to Swift 4.

For more information, see here https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4/blob/master/Whats-new-in-Swift-4.playground/Pages/Key%20paths.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift

Comment: Thanks, This method is very simple for removing KVO.

Answer (score 32):

I had a lot of trouble trying to figure out the status of an `AVPlayer`. The `status` property didn't always seem to be terribly helpful, and this led to endless frustration when I was trying to handle audio session interruptions. Sometimes the `AVPlayer` told me it was ready to play (with `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`) when it didn't actually seem to be. I used Jilouc's KVO method, but it didn't work in all cases.

To supplement, when the status property wasn't being useful, I queried the amount of the stream that the AVPlayer had loaded by looking at the `loadedTimeRanges` property of the `AVPlayer`'s `currentItem` (which is an `AVPlayerItem`).

It's all a little confusing, but here's what it looks like:

```
NSValue *val = [[[audioPlayer currentItem] loadedTimeRanges] objectAtIndex:0];
CMTimeRange timeRange;
[val getValue:&timeRange];
CMTime duration = timeRange.duration;
float timeLoaded = (float) duration.value / (float) duration.timescale; 

if (0 == timeLoaded) {
    // AVPlayer not actually ready to play
} else {
    // AVPlayer is ready to play
}
```

Comment: There are additions to the NSValue type coming with AV Foundation. Some of those helpers allow you to convert back and forth from NSValue to CMTimeXxx values. Like [CMTimeRangeValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/NSValue_AVFoundation_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSValue/CMTimeRangeValue).

Comment: Similar story for getting seconds (I guess that's what `timeLoaded` is) out of CMTime: [CMTimeGetSeconds](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMTimeGetSeconds)

Comment: Unfortunately, this should be an accepted answer. `AVPlayer` seems to set `status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` too early when it is not ready to play really. To make this work, you can wrap the above code in `NSTimer` invocation, for example.

Comment: Could it be the case where there are over (w.l.o.g) 2 seconds of loaded time range, but the player's or playerItem's status isn't ReadyToPlay? IOW, should it be confirmed as well?

Answer (score 19):

```
private var playbackLikelyToKeepUpContext = 0
```

For register observer

```
avPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp",
        options: .new, context: &playbackLikelyToKeepUpContext)
```

Listen the observer

```
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == &playbackLikelyToKeepUpContext {
        if avPlayer.currentItem!.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
           // loadingIndicatorView.stopAnimating() or something else
        } else {
           // loadingIndicatorView.startAnimating() or something else
        }
    }
}
```

For remove observer

```
deinit {
    avPlayer.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
}
```

The key point in the code is instance property isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp.

Comment: Good answer. I would improve KVO with `forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp)`

Comment: For 2019, **this does work perfectly** - copy and paste :)  I did use the mod of @MiroslavHrivik , thanks!

Comment: @MiroslavHrivik with his correction in the implementation it works in 2021, thank you

Comment: @StackGU If I have a player inside of a VideoCell item, should I put this answer's code inside of this VideoCell class or should I create a new class for the observer? I'm a newbie and somehow confused with KVO in Swift

Comment: @BenjamínCáceresRamirez put it inside the ```collectionViewCell``` but remember to remove the observer inside the ```prepareForReuse()``` method

Comment: I used static variable for context, otherwise compiler complains. Like below:
private static var playbackLikelyToKeepUpContext = 0

Answer (score 11):

After researching a lot and try many ways I've noticed that normally the **`status` observer is not the better for know really when `AVPlayer` object is ready to play**, because the object can be ready for play but this not that mean it will be play immediately.

The better idea for know this is with `loadedTimeRanges`.

> For Register observer

```
[playerClip addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

> Listen the observer

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == playerClip && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"]) {
        NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray*)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        if (timeRanges && [timeRanges count]) {
            CMTimeRange timerange=[[timeRanges objectAtIndex:0]CMTimeRangeValue];
            float currentBufferDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeAdd(timerange.start, timerange.duration));
            CMTime duration = playerClip.currentItem.asset.duration;
            float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);

            //I think that 2 seconds is enough to know if you're ready or not
            if (currentBufferDuration > 2 || currentBufferDuration == seconds) {
                // Ready to play. Your logic here
            }
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert!" message:@"Error trying to play the clip. Please try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        }
    }
}
```

> For remove observer (dealloc, viewWillDissapear or before register observer) its a good places for called

```
- (void)removeObserverForTimesRanges
{
    @try {
        [playerClip removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"];
    } @catch(id anException){
        NSLog(@"excepcion remove observer == %@. Remove previously or never added observer.",anException);
        //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me as well. I however did not use the "currentBufferDuration == seconds" evaluation. Could you please tell me what it's used for?

Comment: For cases when `currentBufferDuration < 2`

Comment: Could it be the case where there are over (w.l.o.g) 2 seconds of loaded time range, but the player's or playerItem's status isn't ReadyToPlay? IOW, should it be confirmed as well?

Answer (score 7):

Based on [Tim Camber answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746960/1327557), here is the Swift function I use :

```
private func isPlayerReady(_ player:AVPlayer?) -> Bool {

    guard let player = player else { return false }

    let ready = player.status == .readyToPlay

    let timeRange = player.currentItem?.loadedTimeRanges.first as? CMTimeRange
    guard let duration = timeRange?.duration else { return false } // Fail when loadedTimeRanges is empty
    let timeLoaded = Int(duration.value) / Int(duration.timescale) // value/timescale = seconds
    let loaded = timeLoaded > 0

    return ready && loaded
}
```

Or, as an extension

```
extension AVPlayer {
    var ready:Bool {
        let timeRange = currentItem?.loadedTimeRanges.first as? CMTimeRange
        guard let duration = timeRange?.duration else { return false }
        let timeLoaded = Int(duration.value) / Int(duration.timescale) // value/timescale = seconds
        let loaded = timeLoaded > 0

        return status == .readyToPlay && loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: With the extension, I guess it's not possible to KVO observe the ready property. Any way around?

Comment: I listen to the notifications `AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntry` and `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` in my project. Afaik it works.

Comment: OK, I ended up listening to `loadedTimeRanges`.

Answer (score 5):

I had issues with not getting any callbacks.

Turns out it depends on how you create the stream. In my case I used a playerItem to initialize, and thus I had to add the observer to the item instead.

For example:

```
- (void) setup
{
    ...
    self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playerItem];
    ... 

     // add callback
     [self.player.currentItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
}

// the callback method
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"[VideoView] player status: %i", self.player.status);

    if (object == self.player.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        if (self.player.currentItem.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
           //do stuff
        }
    }
}

// cleanup or it will crash
-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.player.currentItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
}
```

Comment: The if should not be with `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`?

Comment: @jose920405 I can confirm the solution above works, but its a good question. I really don´t know. Let me know if you test it.

Answer (score 5):

### Swift 4:

```
var player:AVPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReadyToPlay(notification:)),
               name: .AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntry, 
               object: player?.currentItem)
}

@objc func playerItemDidReadyToPlay(notification: Notification) {
        if let _ = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            // player is ready to play now!!
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

[@JoshBernfeld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787854/4833705) didn't work for me. Not sure why. He observed `playerItem.observe(\.status`. I had to observe `player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status`. Seems like they're the same thing, the `playerItem status` property.

```
var playerStatusObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false // starts faster

playerStatusObserver = player?.observe(\.currentItem?.status, options: [.new, .old]) { (player, change) in
        
    switch (player.status) {
    case .readyToPlay:
            // here is where it's ready to play so play player
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.player?.play()
            }
    case .failed, .unknown:
            print("Media Failed to Play")
    @unknown default:
         break
    }
}
```

when you are finished using the player set `playerStatusObserver = nil`

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check the status of the player's currentItem:

```
if (player.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay)
```

Comment: player.currentItem.status returns AVPlayerItemStatusUnkown.
I dont know what to do next. :(

Comment: Initially this value is `AVPlayerItemStatusUnkown`. Only after some time, it will be able to know if it is `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` or `AVPlayerItemStatusFailed`