# How to get thumbnails from any URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In both chat apps, social apps have a feature, when we paste a link on text view it's giving us a thumbnail from that url,
[image]

Is this possible to do in an iOS app. If it is how may I do this?

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you made any attempt at looking for this yourself before asking the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a thumbnail or image of an AVPlayer at current time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360721/create-a-thumbnail-or-image-of-an-avplayer-at-current-time)

Comment: you can create a thumbnail anytime if you have the original image; YouTube basically provides the small thumbnails via its API, so if you use their API you must have seen that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally did it with MTDURLPreview [on github](https://github.com/myell0w/MTDURLPreview)

**Usage**

```
#import "MTDURLPreview.h"

[MTDURLPreview loadPreviewWithURL:@"url here" completion:^(MTDURLPreview *preview, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image URL : %d", [preview.imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]]);
    NSLog(@"Content : %@", preview.content);
    NSLog(@"Title : %@", preview.title);
}];
```

Hope your problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

I would parse html content and try to find links to .png, jpg etc files. Then check the resolution to exclude very small images or those specified as a background in css. As a result a user would get a list of filtered images like on the screenshot you attached.

As a parser you could use https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader

Answer (score 4):

Pages like Facebook use OpenGraph information from web pages to generate thumbnails for links. OpenGraph attributes describe the object presented on a web page. OpenGraph data is stored in meta tags, as shown in A.Krasniqi's answer:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

These meta tags have a prefix of `og`.

Basic OpenGraph attributes include:

- og:title (The title of the object)
- og:type (The type of the object, e.g. video.movie)
- og:url (A permanent, canonical URL to this object)
- og:image (An image representing the page)

Other tags include:

- og:description (A description of the object)
- og:video
- og:audio

All OpenGraph parameters are documented [here](http://ogp.me)

To parse these, you can use `NSXMLParser` but others have implemented OpenGraph parsers. (Just google "iOS OpenGraph parser")

Answer (score 3):

Updated: For new iOS devs, you could use:
https://github.com/itsmeichigo/URLPreview

Use opengraph from facebook, then parse it

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I used and I get the good results.

Source code: **https://github.com/keshiim/WBGLinkPreview**

Cocoapod Name: **pod "WBGLinkPreview"**

I used code inside my class like:

```
#import <WBGLinkPreview/WBGLinkPreview.h>

@interface ViewController ()
 {
     WBGLinkPreview *urlPreview;
 }
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
urlPreview = [[WBGLinkPreview alloc] init];
[urlPreview previewWithText:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHq_ChsWtb0"
                  onSuccess:^(NSDictionary *result) {
                      NSLog(@"Final Output:: %@", result);
                  } onError:^(WBGPreviewError *error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                  }];
}
```