# How to capture still image from custom video player screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, xcode7

I just create my own custom video player using `AVFoundation` library's AVPlayer* myPlayer. Now I want to capture images for bookmarks of video from running playing video on `UIButton` click `action`. On click `UIButton` it take snapshot of player screen and store in document directory.
Please suggest me how to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a thumbnail or image of an AVPlayer at current time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360721/create-a-thumbnail-or-image-of-an-avplayer-at-current-time)

Comment: Help others reproduce the problem, if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:sourceURL];
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC
```

Reference Link :

[Create a thumbnail or image of an AVPlayer at current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360721/create-a-thumbnail-or-image-of-an-avplayer-at-current-time)

Comment: I'm using AVPlayer instead of MPMoviePlayer.

Answer (score 0):

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;


CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:player.currentTime
                                             actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
```