# How to get low quality thumbnail of remote video instantly using AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift2

I'm receiving a high/medium quality thumbnail of remote video by AVAssetImageGenerator, but still it takes 10 to 15 seconds to get thumbnail out of it.
Is there any way to get low quality thumbnail instantly?
below code I've used to get thumbnail of remote video.
The strange is when I download this video it's size was 1.1 MB and created Thumbnail size is 1.8 MB.

```
let assetForThumbnail = AVAsset(URL: videoURL)
let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(assetForThumbnail.duration)
let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: assetForThumbnail)
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
let time = CMTime(seconds: durationSeconds/3.0, preferredTimescale: 600)

generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes([NSValue(CMTime: time)]) { (requestedTime: CMTime, thumbnail: CGImage?, actualTime: CMTime, result: AVAssetImageGeneratorResult, error: NSError?) in
     print("error: \(error)")
     print("status: \(result)")

     if let thumbnailC = thumbnail {
          let image = UIImage(CGImage: thumbnailC)
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `AVAssetImageGenerator`'s `maximumSize` property like this:

> generator.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 320)

Comment: If the problem is not the quality, but the time taken for the operation, you may want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10225553/1502621

Comment: Hi Vlad, I understood your point and I tried your link and answers on it. whereas **pascalbros** answer I tried, but still taking a same time. and **Nimit Parekh** answer won't help, because MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated on 9.0

Comment: Hi Vlad, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360721/create-a-thumbnail-or-image-of-an-avplayer-at-current-time