# How to replace AVPlayer thumbnail image?

Tags: objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller, video-thumbnails

Is there any way to replace AVPlayer thumbnail image? I need to add a custom image as thumbnail layer

Comment: I think you want to set Thumbnail for video right?

Comment: If yes pls refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360721/create-a-thumbnail-or-image-of-an-avplayer-at-current-time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got a simple solution for this. **we can add any UIImage to the contentOverlayView, it will not hide the Play/Pause controls and we can hide this imageView later.**

```
[self.moviePlayerController.contentOverlayView addSubview:placeHolderImageView];
```