# Adding activity indicator while AVplayer gets ready to play music

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, avplayer

I developed an app for radio and it's working.

I want to put an activity indicator view so that when you touch the play it starts the activity indicator view and when the audio starts, the activity indicator stops.

Comment: Do you want clarification on how to add the activity indicator? Are you getting callbacks on pressing play button and before starting player?

Comment: Have you tried to use AVPlayerViewController? It already contains activity indicator that indicates all loading progress + AVPlayer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will add the activity view to the center of the view. Add this code in the "IBAction" where u handle the **play button.**

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;

    [activityView startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
    [self.view userInteractionEnabled:NO];   //to avoid touch events when activity is on
```

And to stop the activity indicator use

```
[activityView stopAnimating];    
[activityView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view userInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

This is from [this link about AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html). and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5403162/1383704) ->

Using KVO, it's possible to be notified for changes of the player status:

```
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

In the **PLAY button's** event add the code to start the `UIActivityIndicator`

This method will be called when the status changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            //DISABLE THE UIACTIVITY INDICATOR HERE
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            // something went wrong. player.error should contain some information
        }
    }
}
```