# How to detect AVPlayer actually started to play in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, uislider

Hello I have set my `UISlider`minimum value to 0.00. Then I set it's max value in this way.

```
self.viewPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    let duration : CMTime = avPlayer.avPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration
    let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)

    sliderBar.maximumValue=Float(seconds)
    sliderBar!.isContinuous = false
    sliderBar!.tintColor = UIColor.green
```

But I am  getting this exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to set a slider's minimumValue (0.000000) to be larger than the maximumValue (nan)'
enter code here
```

I know after `prepareForPlay()` to actual playing it takes some time to really play the video. So how can I detect when the player really started to play the video?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401437/knowing-when-avplayer-object-is-ready-to-play

Comment: Player.play()  is method that play your file so you can track it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yeas. I want to detect when player starts to play actually. Because it takes some time to play after load the video

Comment: This answer of @Jose might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401437/knowing-when-avplayer-object-is-ready-to-play

Answer (score 41):

Since iOS 10 you can observe `timeControlStatus` property of AVPlayer. It can be `.playing`.

Check the code:

```
private func setupAVPlayer() {
    avPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        avPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    } else {
        avPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
    }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if object as AnyObject? === avPlayer {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            if avPlayer.status == .readyToPlay {
                avPlayer.play()
            }
        } else if keyPath == "timeControlStatus" {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                if avPlayer.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                    videoCell?.muteButton.isHidden = false
                } else {
                    videoCell?.muteButton.isHidden = true
                }
            }
        } else if keyPath == "rate" {
            if avPlayer.rate > 0 {
                videoCell?.muteButton.isHidden = false
            } else {
                videoCell?.muteButton.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

Here is what I did to actually know when video **started** (not when it's only ready to start).

**Swift 4**

```
player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        if player.rate > 0 {
            print("video started")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AmritTiwari Well it is Swift 4.

Comment: Have you checked if observeValue() is doing something?

Comment: yeah i have done by using timeobserver method and thanks for the reply.

Comment: This works like a charm, when the player starts and stop, thanks a lot

Answer (score 12):

You can add an observer on the object of your AVPlayer like this

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
```

and you can check the status change with your AVPlayer like this

```
 func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) {
    if keyPath == "status" {
        print(player.status)
    }
}
```

Comment: player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay does this mean the video is started to play?

Comment: this means avplayer will begin to play now.

Comment: This just print as AVPlayerStatus

Comment: Have you tried getting duration here when the status is readyToPlay ?

Comment: @Rajat This does not tell if video is started playing. It only says video is ready to be played. `readyToPlay`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "rate" or "timeControlStatus" are correct answers.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a Combine publisher and observe the `rate` property:

```
let isPlayingPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: AVPlayer.rateDidChangeNotification, object: player)
        .compactMap({ $0.object as? AVPlayer })
        .map(\.rate)
        .map({ $0 != 0 })
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

In SwiftUI you could then receive the value:

```
.onReceive(isPlayingPublisher) { isPlaying in
    
}
```

Comment: `AVPlayer.rateDidChangeNotification` is available in iOS 15+. "Thank you very much"

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html):

`You can observe an AVPlayerLayer object’s readyForDisplay property to be notified when the layer has user-visible content. In particular, you might insert the player layer into the layer tree only when there is something for the user to look at and then perform a transition from`

Answer (score -3):

Declare AVPlayer Global

```
var streamPlayer = AVPlayer()

func playStreamAudio( for audioUrl:String)
    {
        guard streamPlayer.timeControlStatus != .playing else {
            streamPlayer.pause()
            return
        }
        let url = audioUrl //"http://192.168.71.11:7891/rec.wav"
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string:url)!)
        streamPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        streamPlayer.rate = 1.0;
        streamPlayer.volume = 1.0
        streamPlayer.play()
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

**SUPER EASY SOLUTION SWIFT 4-5:**

Just check the `timeControlStatus`!: (also works with PlayerQueue)

```
    if avPlayer?.timeControlStatus.rawValue == 2 {
       
    //video is playing (playing)

    } else if avPlayer?.timeControlStatus.rawValue == 0 { 
    
    //video is not playing (paused)
    
    }
```

the raw value will give you its current state :)

Answer (score -6):

Another, simpler, approach is something like:

```
if videoPlayer.rate != 0 && videoPlayer.error == nil {
            print("video player is playing.................")
        } else {
            print("video player is NOT playing.")
        }
```

Where videoPlayer is of type AVPlayer, obviously.

Comment: but its not reactive