# Initializing an AVPlayerItem with automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys and "duration"

Tags: ios, avasset, avplayeritem

I'm initializing an `AVPlayerItem`, and it takes a parameter `automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys`, which indicates which `AVAsset` keys need to be loaded before it is flagged as "ready to play".

I've seen examples of people passing in the `duration` property as one of these keys.

But then over in the documentation for `AVPlayerItem`, it talks about the `duration` property, and how to make sure that it's valid.

> The value of this property will be reported as kCMTimeIndefinite until the duration of the underlying asset has been loaded. There are two ways to ensure that the value of duration is accessed only after it becomes available:
>
> Wait until the `status` of the player item is `readyToPlay`

The other way is to register a KVO, which is fine. But this first comment would indicate to me that I *do not* need to ask that `duration` gets automatically loaded, because it should be already.(?)

If this is true, I can't figure out why anyone would ever pass in `duration` as a flag to be automatically loaded, because it looks like that's the case. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I know this is a little stale. But I recently found the answer to my problem.

So, I realized that I was getting the documentation confused, and it was probably right in the docs all along, if I had looked harder, I would've noticed.

`AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)` loads the `duration` property by default. It's just like calling `AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: ["duration"])`

It actually says this in the docs, but I completely missed it.

Answer (score 3):

Some people do this because there are iOS bugs (including in iOS 12.1.4) which sometimes cause AVPlayerItem.duration to be nan, even when status is readyToPlay. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382686/avplayeritem-duration-returns-as-nan-even-after-player-status-readytoplay/43382924) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874574/avplayer-item-get-a-nan-duration/31408035).

However, my experience is specifying "duration" in automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys does not solve the issue - despite Apple's docs for [AVPlayerItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1387529-init):

> The value of each key in automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys will automatically be loaded by the underlying AVAsset before the player item achieves the status AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay; i.e. when the item is ready to play, the value returned by invoking the asset property’s statusOfValue(forKey:error:) method will be one of the terminal status values

I can get AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay, with statusOfValue(forKey: "duration") returning .loaded, and the duration nan.

The only solution I've found that works every time is to KVO both AVPlayerItem.status (for .readyToPlay) and AVPlayerItem.duration (for a valid number), and when either triggers, check both:

```
    if item.status != AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay || !item.duration.isUsableNumber() {
        return // not ready yet (for addBoundaryTimeObserver, seek to end, etc.)
    }
```

Where isUsableNunber() is just:

```
 func isUsableNumber() -> Bool {
    return isValid && isNumeric && !isIndefinite && !isNegativeInfinity && !isPositiveInfinity
}
```