# Is loadedTimeRanges enough to indicate AVPlayer is ready to play?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer

`AVPlayer` has 2 *formal* conditions that should hold to indicate it's [ready to play](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388096-status):

1. `status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay`.
2. `currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`.

Several developers had noticed that these indicators are not enough, and videos don't actually start playing until `loadedTimeRanges` indicates ready-ness (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9746960/6025342) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926322/6025342) for implementation details).

These properties should be observed to be put to use, which is costly.

Does a **non-zero value** in `loadedTimeRanges` indicates that the player and playerItem's statuses are ready? This can save 2 observations.