# Load AVAsset video in the background and replace playing placeholder video once it's playable in Swift and RealityKit

Tags: swift, avfoundation, realitykit

I'm using the following code to create a video player for detected reference images in AR session. Currently I display a placeholder video and after 1 second switch to real video that I want played. However, I would like to show the placeholder video until the real video is ready to be played.

I tried experimenting with AVAsset and observing the playable status based on this: [Knowing when AVPlayer object is ready to play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401437/knowing-when-avplayer-object-is-ready-to-play) - however I didn't have any success.

```
        func createVideoNode(_ target: ARReferenceImage) -> ModelEntity {
        var videoPlane = ModelEntity()
        var targetName: String = ""
        
        if let name = target.name,
           let validURL = URL(string: "https://testdomain.com/\(name).mp4") {
            targetName = name

            // Use the preloaded placeholder asset to create an AVPlayer
            if let placeholderAsset = parent.placeholderAsset {
                let placeholderPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: placeholderAsset))
                let videoMaterial = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: placeholderPlayer)
                videoPlane = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: Float(target.physicalSize.width), depth: Float(target.physicalSize.height)), materials: [videoMaterial])
                placeholderPlayer.play()

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: validURL)
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: videoPlayer.currentItem, queue: .main) { [weak videoPlayer] _ in
                        videoPlayer?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
                        videoPlayer?.play()
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                        let videoMaterial = VideoMaterial(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
                        videoPlane.model?.materials = [videoMaterial]
                        videoPlayer.play()
                        self.parent.videoPlayers[targetName] = videoPlayer
                        print (target.name as Any)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                fatalError("Failed to load placeholder video asset.")
            }
        }

        return videoPlane
    }
```